# Merge all records in SAS

Tags: sas

I have two data sets. `Table1` has just one record. `Table2` has many records. I want to combine these so that the variables from `Table1` are added to every record in `Table2`.

I know this can be done with `proc sql` like this:

```
proc sql;
 create table3 as
  select *
  from table1, table2;
quit;
```

I want the same result, but using a data step. What's the best (elegant, efficient) way to do this?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
data table3;
if _n_ = 1 then set table1;
set table2;
run;
```

That's the simplest way.

Comment: This works, but I'm confused. It looks like table1 is just being read once, when `_n_=1`. Can you explain what's going on? Thanks!

Comment: Table 1 is indeed being read only once, when _n_ = 1 - hence why you don't reach EOF marker on table 1 and end the data step after 1 iteration (well, after the start of 2 iterations).
What's happening is any variable that comes in via set/merge/update is automatically RETAINed (more accurately, are NOT set to zero for each iteration), and thus all of the variables from Table1 are retained through the iterations.

Comment: http://www2.sas.com/proceedings/sugi28/103-28.pdf explains it in slightly better detail than my explanation (near the beginning).

Comment: @Joe Am I missing something here, or does a merge not do the same?
`data table3;
merge table1 table2;
run;`

Comment: You're missing something :)  Merge does not merge on to every record.  Because it's without a BY statement, it will be a side by side merge, so each record gets the value from each side of the same record number; so if table1 has 1 row and table2 has 5, then table3 has table1's value on row one only, and table2's values on all five.  Further, most production systems will not allow a merge without a BY statement (as that is more commonly a mistake in coding than a valid solution).

Comment: If you did want to use MERGE, you could have a value that had the same value for every record of table1 and table2, then merge on it - ie, _dummy_=1; for both tables, then merge on _dummy_.  But that wouldn't really accomplish anything useful since you can do it with SET.